# SKSpriteNode Array with name change?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, loops, sprite-kit

Im fairly new to using arrays, and was playing around with the following code in swift playgrounds:

```
var array = [SKSpriteNode]()
let sprite = SKSpriteNode()

sprite.name = "off"
print(sprite.name!) // "off"
array.append(sprite)
sprite.name = "on"
print(sprite.name!) // "on"

for i in array {
print(i.name!) // "on" ???
}
```

The name of the sprite is "off". I then add this sprite to the array. Next I change the name of the sprite to "on".

When I check the name of the sprite with a for loop within the array, its name is "on"?

Why is this? I thought arrays just held information, therefore the sprite.name in the array would be the sprite.name when I added it? Or are they linked? Does changing the sprite.name outside the array also change the sprite.name inside the array?

Sorry if I am not fully understanding this.

Thanks!

Comment: is there even a question here? sounds like you've already answered this yourself. It is an array of SKSpriteNodes therefore if you change that nodes info it changes in the array. You may want to look at copy() on a SpriteNode if you want to have a version that is left unchanged

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to confirm that this was the case, and it wasn't my coding error.